# Parsing a unix log file

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I am trying to read a log file line by line for a specific string and its values.

For example I have a log file like below:

```
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT> <Error> <comApp> <ap001> <Server12> <[ACTIVE]      ExecuteThread: '55' for queue:    'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <>    <>    <1380175522589> <000000> <<ERROR>Exception ID: 971 -  Rate with    ResParameters-> MAT: SJC GHT: FJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013>     
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT> <Error> <comApp> <ap001> <Server12> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '55' for queue:    'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <>    <1380175522593> <000000> <<ERROR>Exception ID: 971 -  Rate with    ResParameters-> MAT: SJC GHT: FJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013>     
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT> <> <Error> <comApp> <ap001> <Server12> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '55' for queue:    'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <>    <1380175522597> <000000> <<ERROR>Exception ID: 971 -  Rate with    ResParameters-> MAT: SJC GHT: FJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013>
```

I need to read values from defined strings MAT:, GHT:, PUD:

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
SJC , FJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
DJA , SJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
FJC , KJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
JJC , SJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
```

Comment: I think `sed` will be a good tool for such a problem. You can easly find tutorials, and ask here If you have any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -F'\W*(?:MAT|GHT|PUD):\W*' -lane'shift@F; s|>\s*$||for@F; print join", ",@F' file
```

output

```
SJC, FJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
SJC, FJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
SJC, FJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.*MAT:\s*(\w+)\s+GHT:\s*(\w+)\s+PUD:\s*(.+)\s*>/\1, \2, \3/g' infile > outfile
```

Same search and replace can be used in `perl`

```
perl -pe 's/.*MAT:\s*(\w+)\s+GHT:\s*(\w+)\s+PUD:\s*(.+)\s*>/\1, \2, \3/g' infile > outfile
```

Test on your sample data:

```
$ cat infile 
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT>  <<anonymous>> <>  MAT: SJC GHT: FJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013 > 
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT>  <<anonymous>> <>  MAT: DJA GHT: SJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013 >
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT>  <<anonymous>> <>  MAT: FJC GHT: KJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013 >
 ####<Sep 26, 2013 12:05:22 AM MDT>  <<anonymous>> <>  MAT: JJC GHT: SJC PUD: Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013 >

$ cat outfile 
SJC, FJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013 
DJA, SJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
FJC, KJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
JJC, SJC, Fri Sep 27 09:00:00 MDT 2013
```

Comment: @RitheshB.P it seems your `sed` doesn't support extended regular expressions. they you need to escape may characters in `s///g`. Instead try same with `perl`

Comment: @RitheshB.P try using `perl` solution in the second line as suggested

Comment: Let me explain: `-r` is `GNU sed`'s switch for turning on extended regular expressions. As you are on Solaris and not using `GNU sed` you don't have the option. If you read `man sed` you can find out which option turns on extended regular expressions, it's probably `-E`.

Comment: @sudo_O Thanks for this info. Can you edit my ans with this info? I will accept edit. I was not aware. Anyway, I have edited ans with `sed` only regex.

Comment: @jkshah you are actually still using extended regular expressions. The escaping to allow ERE without explicitly turning it on is also a GNU extension so will not help. Look up the difference between `BRE`, `ERE` and `PCRE`.

Comment: hi i have updated the log file perl is working but if I use above updated log file i wont get the expected output

Comment: @sudo_O oops! too many problems! I hope perl may work.

Comment: yes log file has lot of columns i have removed it and made it short

Comment: @RitheshB.P I can't see any edit. log file still looks the same to me.

Comment: so for about log file what modification i need to do

Comment: @RitheshB.P don't modify log file in my ans. Edit it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged Perl

```
perl -ne 'if($_=~/MAT: (\S+) GHT: (\S+) PUD: (\S+ \S+ \d+ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \S+ \d\d\d\d)/){ print "$1,$2,$3\n" ;}' test.txt
```